# Abstract algebra and group theory. Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

What is the general criteria to find subgroups of any group, say a group of order suppose order 8.

I know the basic definitions but don't know how to use it practically.

Comment: One thing that can be said is Lagrange theorem: "For any finite group $G$, the order (number of elements) of every subgroup $H$ of $G$ divides the order of $G$."

Answer (score 0):

For a group that small, you could consider all subsets and see which ones are groups. You can already eliminate all subsets that do not contain $e.$ Slightly more efficiently, you could start with the smallest subsets and find the subgroup that each subset generates (you no longer need to test any subset that is contained in a subgroup already generated).

For example, start with all the cyclic subgroups, i.e., subgroups generated by a single element. These take the form

$$\{e, x, x^2,\ldots,x^7\}$$

where the number of distinct elements may actually be smaller than 8, depending on the order of the element $x$ (always a divisor of 8, as a consequence of Lagrange's theorem).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an algorithm, other than trial and error, to find all subgroups, because a group may not have any non-trivial subgroups.

However, there are some useful things to know. Lagrange's theorem tells us that any subgroup has a size which divides the cardinality of $G$. In your case, any subgroup must have $1$, $2$, $4$, or $8$ elements. Clearly the only subgroup of $1$ element is $\{e\}$ itself, and the only subgroup of $8$ is $G$ itself.

The next step is to take elements and see what group they generate. If $G$ is the integers modulo $8$, then consider $1$. This generates the whole of $G$, since $1+1=2$, $2+1=3$, etc. However, if we consider a subgroup generated by $2$, then we get $2$, $4$, $6$, and $0$ — a subgroup of cardinality $4$.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, what if we need to find the number of subgroups of order 8, of a group having elements of order 8?

Comment: Again, it always depends on the group, but a subgroup generated by an element of order $8$ also has order $8$. Also consider that you can have more than $1$ generator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group

Comment: No there is a question that: G has 8 elements of order 3. How many subgroups of order 3 does G have?

Comment: Well, there is an algorithm, but none that would be feasible to run by hand.